# Android- Force visible soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, hide, android-softkeyboard, enter

i've an edittext that when I click on enter (not button) , the soft keyboard disappears. How can i do to close the soft keyboard only with BACK button, and not with other events?

```
if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code may show the keyboard programmatically. Just catch the KeyEvent as you are doing in your question code and place this code inside that function:

```
yourEditText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.showSoftInput(mUserNameEdit, 0);
        }
    },0);
```

I do not recommend using InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED because it can cause strange layout issues. I would rather use this snippet in that case:

`InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);`

Comment: it works great, thx, but there is a way to not make visible the keyboard blinking with this method? Because i've seen that when i click enter the keyboard disappear and after that it reopens up. I've to set to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the onCreate() of your activity.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```